# Who wants my alien medi-gel formula?

Tags: mass-effect-3

While raiding a Cerberus base, I came across a medi-gel formula that they ignored because it doesn't help humans. My mission log tells me someone on the Citadel will be interested, so when the mission was over I flew right back and ran around the Citadel looking for the interested party, even triple-checking the Hospital, and can't find anyone who wants it.

[image]

Who do I give the alien medi-gel formula to?

Comment: Dirtiest question title yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A human doctor will be looking for the medi-gel formula you have in your possession following the completion of your mission on Palaven. You can find her in lobby of the Huerta Memorial Hospital on the Citadel, to your left when you walk in the door:

[image: doctor who's looking for medi-gel]

Outside of having completed the Palaven mission, there's nothing in particular that you need to do to trigger this mission beyond talking to her once in possession of the forumla. As [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer) notes in the comments, the doctor does have a side-conversation that would clue you into her need for the formula to begin with which you'll overheard as you approach her.

Comment: You may need to hang around long enough for her to finish her dialog also.

Comment: So I went to YouTube and found a video of someone doing this. Then I went there in my game. That doctor simply isn't there yet for me. Must not appear until a certain trigger point.

Comment: @Sterno I'd be willing to believe that you had to complete Palaven first as Valik suggested, but as far as I know that's the only thing I had done in the game so far beyond getting the formula.

Comment: @TimStone Confirmed. After getting back from Palaven, the doctor was now there. I'll accept if you update your answer.

Comment: @Sterno Ah ha, I suppose that does make sense. Answer updated, and thanks for checking; I was planning to myself, but trying to finish up my first playthrough at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

When I first came to the hospital after getting the formula, she was not here.
But she was after I did a mission (Palaven).

Comment: This is probably the missing piece of the puzzle for me.